# Why cant I pass a variable from one .java file to another?

Tags: java, class, user-interface, netbeans

There is something odd going on in my code. I'm making a Connect Four game, but making it to where you can have up to eight teams with four players each. There are three separate GUI class files, each with their own layout, etc. But I cannot pass a variable from the SettingsGUI file to the TeamSettingsGUI file, despite my best efforts. What is weird, is how I can initialize the variable, or have the getXXX method return a certain number and it works fine. But I am unable to pass the value of the variable, for some reason.

The two variables I am dealing with right now are numTeams and playersPerTeam. IF I could understand how to get one of them to work, I think I could get the rest of them to work as well. I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm stumped.
Here's the int ital GUI, SettingsGUI:

```
package connectfouradvanced;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SettingsGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

JLabel saveLabel = new JLabel("Saved. Please exit this GUI.");
JButton save = new JButton("Save");

    JLabel numTeamsLabel = new JLabel("Chose the number of teams.");
    Choice numTeamsChoice = new Choice();

    JLabel boardDimensionsLabel = new JLabel("Chose the board dimensions.");
    Choice boardDimensionsChoice = new Choice();

    JLabel numPlayersPerTeamLabel = new JLabel("Chose the number of players per team.");
    Choice numPlayersPerTeamChoice = new Choice();

    JLabel powerupsLabel = new JLabel("Powerups On/Off?");
    JCheckBox powerups = new JCheckBox();

    JLabel standardLabel = new JLabel("Standard Setup?");
    JCheckBox standardSettings = new JCheckBox();

    int numTeams, boardRows, boardColumns, playersPerTeam; 
    //if you were to put numTeams = 4, then 4 would be passed to TeamSettingsGUI
    boolean powerupsSelected = false, standardSelected;

public SettingsGUI() {
    add(saveLabel);
    saveLabel.setVisible(false);

    add(save);
    save.addActionListener(this);

    add(numTeamsLabel);
    add(numTeamsChoice);
    numTeamsChoice.add("2");
    numTeamsChoice.add("3");
    numTeamsChoice.add("4");
    numTeamsChoice.add("5");
    numTeamsChoice.add("6");
    numTeamsChoice.add("7");
    numTeamsChoice.add("8");

    add(boardDimensionsLabel);
    add(boardDimensionsChoice);
    boardDimensionsChoice.add("7x6");
    boardDimensionsChoice.add("14x12");
    boardDimensionsChoice.add("21x18");
    boardDimensionsChoice.add("28x24");
    boardDimensionsChoice.add("35x30");
    boardDimensionsChoice.add("42x36");
    boardDimensionsChoice.add("49x42");
    boardDimensionsChoice.add("56x48");
    boardDimensionsChoice.add("63x54");
    boardDimensionsChoice.add("70x60");

    add(numPlayersPerTeamLabel);
    add(numPlayersPerTeamChoice);
    numPlayersPerTeamChoice.add("1");
    numPlayersPerTeamChoice.add("2");
    numPlayersPerTeamChoice.add("3");
    numPlayersPerTeamChoice.add("4");

    add(powerupsLabel);
    add(powerups);
    powerups.setSelected(true);

    add(standardLabel);
    add(standardSettings);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
    super.paintComponent(g);

    saveLabel.setLocation(150, 100);
    save.setLocation(315, 90);

    numTeamsLabel.setLocation(0, 0);
    numTeamsChoice.setLocation(170, 0);
    numTeamsChoice.setSize(40, 15);

    boardDimensionsLabel.setLocation(0, 25);
    boardDimensionsChoice.setLocation(170, 25);
    boardDimensionsChoice.setSize(80, 15);

    numPlayersPerTeamLabel.setLocation(0, 50);
    numPlayersPerTeamChoice.setLocation(225, 50);
    numPlayersPerTeamChoice.setSize(40, 15);

    powerupsLabel.setLocation(0, 75);
    powerups.setLocation(110, 75);

    standardLabel.setLocation(0, 100);
    standardSettings.setLocation(110, 100);
}

public void saveSettings() {
    switch(numTeamsChoice.getSelectedIndex()) {
        case 0: numTeams = 2; break;
        case 1: numTeams = 3; break;
        case 2: numTeams = 4; break;
        case 3: numTeams = 5; break;
        case 4: numTeams = 6; break;
        case 5: numTeams = 7; break;
        case 6: numTeams = 8; break;
    }

    switch(boardDimensionsChoice.getSelectedIndex()) {
        case 0: boardColumns = 7; boardRows = 6; break;
        case 1: boardColumns = 14; boardRows = 12; break;
        case 2: boardColumns = 21; boardRows = 18; break;
        case 3: boardColumns = 28; boardRows = 24; break;
        case 4: boardColumns = 35; boardRows = 30; break;
        case 5: boardColumns = 42; boardRows = 36; break;
        case 6: boardColumns = 49; boardRows = 42; break;
        case 7: boardColumns = 56; boardRows = 48; break;
        case 8: boardColumns = 63; boardRows = 54; break;
        case 9: boardColumns = 70; boardRows = 60; break;
    }

    switch(numPlayersPerTeamChoice.getSelectedIndex()) {
        case 0: playersPerTeam = 1; break;
        case 1: playersPerTeam = 2; break;
        case 2: playersPerTeam = 3; break;
        case 3: playersPerTeam = 4; break;
    }

    if(powerups.isSelected() == true) {
        powerupsSelected = true;
    }

    if(standardSettings.isSelected() == true) {
        standardSelected = true;
        powerupsSelected = false;
        numTeams = 2;
        boardColumns = 7;
        boardRows = 6;
        playersPerTeam = 1;
    }

    saveLabel.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("Using standard settings? " + standardSelected);
    System.out.println("Powerups enabled? " + powerupsSelected);
    System.out.println(numTeams + " " + boardColumns + " " + boardRows + " " + playersPerTeam);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(save)) {
        saveSettings();
    }
}

public int getBoardColumns() {
    return boardColumns;
}

public int getBoardRows() {
    return boardRows;
}

public int getNumTeams() {
    return numTeams;
    //again, put return 4; here and it will return 4 to TeamSettingsGUI
}

public int getPlayersPerTeam(){
    return playersPerTeam;
}

public boolean getPowerupsEnabled() {
    return powerupsSelected;
}

public boolean getStandardEnabled() {
    return standardSelected;
}
```

}

Now remember, where I initialize numTeams and playersPerTeam, it can pass through to TeamSettingsGUI perfectly. I have a feeling that in saveSettings() it's not saving the variable, it's only temporary. If it is, then I don't know how to fix it. I've tried stuff like this.numPlayers in the switch case and everything.

Here is the TeamSettingsGUI:

```
package connectfouradvanced;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TeamSettingsGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    SettingsGUI settings = new SettingsGUI();
    int numTeams = settings.getNumTeams();
    int playersPerTeam = settings.getPlayersPerTeam();

    JButton saveTeam = new JButton();

    Color[] teamColors = new Color[numTeams];
    String[][] playerNames = new String[numTeams][playersPerTeam];
    char[][] playerSymbols = new char[numTeams][playersPerTeam];

    Choice[] colors = new Choice[numTeams];
    String[] colorList = {"Red", "Yellow", "Orange", "Green", "Black", "Blue", "Cyan",     "Magenta"};

    JCheckBox[] ready = new JCheckBox[numTeams];
    JLabel[] teamNumbers = new JLabel[numTeams];
    JTextField[][] playerNamesInput = new JTextField[numTeams][playersPerTeam];
    JTextField[][] playerSymbolsInput = new JTextField[numTeams][playersPerTeam];

public TeamSettingsGUI() {
    add(saveTeam);
    saveTeam.addActionListener(this);

    for(int i = 0; i < teamNumbers.length; i++) {
        teamNumbers[i] = new JLabel();
        teamNumbers[i].setText("Team " + (i + 1));
        add(teamNumbers[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        colors[i] = new Choice();
        colors[i].add("Red");
        colors[i].add("Yellow");
        colors[i].add("Orange");
        colors[i].add("Green");
        colors[i].add("Black");
        colors[i].add("Blue");
        colors[i].add("Cyan");
        colors[i].add("Magenta");
        colors[i].select(colorList[i]);
        add(colors[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < playerNamesInput.length; i++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < playerNamesInput[i].length; k++) {
            playerNamesInput[i][k] = new JTextField();
            playerNamesInput[i][k].setText("Team " + (i+1) + " player " + (k+1) + " name: ");
            add(playerNamesInput[i][k]);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < playerSymbolsInput.length; i++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < playerSymbolsInput[i].length; k++) {
            playerSymbolsInput[i][k] = new JTextField();
            playerSymbolsInput[i][k].setText("Team " + (i+1) + " player " + (k+1) + " symbol: ");
            add(playerSymbolsInput[i][k]);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < ready.length; i++) {
        ready[i] = new JCheckBox();
        ready[i].setText("Ready?");
        add(ready[i]);
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(saveTeam)) {

    }
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
    super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println(numTeams + " " + playersPerTeam);
}
```

Note, TeamSettingsGUI is NOT complete. I can't continue on with aligning things and whatnot until I fix this.
Sorry if my code is dirty or anything, but I just cant figure out what's going on.

Forgot to include the main executable class, there is another missing BoardGUI class that is empty for now.

```
    package connectfouradvanced;
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class ConnectFourAdvanced {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SettingsGUI s = new SettingsGUI();
    BoardGUI b = new BoardGUI();
    TeamSettingsGUI t = new TeamSettingsGUI();

    JFrame fs = new JFrame();
    JFrame fb = new JFrame();
    JFrame ft = new JFrame();
    fs.add(s);
    fb.add(b);
    ft.add(t);

    fs.setVisible(true);
    fs.setResizable(false);
    fs.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    fs.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    fs.setSize(400, 150);
    fs.setTitle("Settings");

    while(fs.isVisible() == true) {
        ft.setVisible(false);
    }

    ft.setVisible(true);
    ft.setResizable(false);
    ft.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    ft.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ft.setSize(1200, 500);
    ft.setTitle("Team Settings");

    while(ft.isVisible() == true || fs.isVisible() == true) {
        fb.setVisible(false);
    }

    fb.setVisible(true);
    fb.setResizable(false);
    fb.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    fb.setLocation(100, 100);
    fb.setSize(1000, 1000);
    fb.setTitle("Connect Four");
}
```

}

I would like to add that I am only 16, and while I'm not that bad at java, GUIs and objects are still pretty new to me. So if my code is clunky or cluttered, or I'm doing some pretty dumb things that seem simple to others, it's because I'm new to this. This is my first big GUI project that I started on my own.

Comment: Are you sure all that code is strictly required to get your point accross?   It will make it easier if you could reduce your code to as few lines as are needed.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how else to do it. There's just a lot of things to determine, and things like adding choices to the Choice menus make the code seem giant, along with the switch-cases to determine what is selected.

Comment: And you are positive that without that, we wouldn't understand your question?

Comment: I wanted to post my entire code so just in case I messed up somewhere that I hadn't thought I messed up, somebody could see it. Sorry if it's an inconvenience to you.

Comment: Next time post snippets of code, or a very simple example.  It's also a great way to debug, if you create a simple example and it works (just passing the variable) then you would know it's something else, if it's not something else then either debug it yourself or post your example here.  If it is something else, then keep adding more things in till you find the problem, then post that example here.  @GlennTeitelbaum is right, it was a pain to look through your code...

Comment: @SIlkySmoothNuts The folks on StackOverflow are generally most useful answering specific problems, not for code reviews. People who post questions with this much code are pretty much always asked to reduce their problem down to smaller snippets of code. That said, have you tried using a debugger to step through your code? Another idea is to try adding a `default:` statement to each of your `switch` statements, to see if your program is getting some unexpected value.

Comment: Sorry guys, first time posting here, I'll keep this stuff in mind. And I'll try that now.

Comment: Because you don't pass variables between .java files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having issues is that in TeamSettings, you are creating a new instance of SettingsGUI.

Think of it like buying a new car.  If you had a car and then put all of your stuff in it, then bought another car which is exactly the same, would the new car have all of your stuff in it?  No, At least I hope not, if it does let me know, we could make some money together... :)

Here is the line in question:

```
SettingsGUI settings = new SettingsGUI();
```

I would suggest that you use a [Singleton](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm%20%22Singleton) pattern for the work you are doing.  Put your settings in there and then you can reference them anywhere.  There are more complex alternatives, but for the level of work you are doing, I would think a singleton would be your best bet.

Comment: I had just placed that in there, because any other time, with anything else I would do, I would get the error "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context", even though nothing is declared as static. Would this bring up the same error?

Comment: @SIlkySmoothNuts - Use the Singleton pattern, it's explained in the link in my post.  That will solve your issues... :) - Also, you want to be able to access the variables from another class.  Which file it is in is unimportant, you don't pass things between files...

Comment: I'll try it out, thanks for the help. And well, you know, different classes in another file, getting stuff kind of mixed up, sorry.

Comment: I'm getting it to come through mostly, even though it's being kinda picky. Thanks a lot, though. I just didn't know what to do here.

Comment: In what way is it being picky?  Post another question and post a comment here, I'll take a look and help you out...  Going to be asleep in like 20 mins though, so be quick! :)